# why the opengl can't print string

Tags: string, opengl

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <gl/glut.h>
void resizeEvent(int w, int h)
{
    glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluOrtho2D(0, w, h, 0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

void displayEvent()
{
    glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glutSwapBuffers();
    char text[] = "Hello World!";
    glRasterPos2d(110, 110);
    glColor3f(1, 0, 0);
    for(int i=0; text[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        glutBitmapCharacter(GLUT_BITMAP_8_BY_13, text[i]);
    }

}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutInitWindowSize(400, 300);
    glutInitWindowPosition(0, 0);
    glutCreateWindow("Hello");
    glutDisplayFunc(displayEvent);
    glutReshapeFunc(resizeEvent);
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

I learn from a ppt,and think it will print a string.But it does not work .I search from google,but no answer. I don't know why it can't print a string.
if `glutBitmapCharacter` is wrong ?

Comment: The `glutSwapBuffers()` call needs to be at the end of the `displayEvent()` function. It signals that you finished rendering your frame, and are ready for it to be displayed.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

All the commands in opengl, renders on the frame buffer only when flush or finish call happens, so all your commands are still in queue and yet to be displayed on frame buffer. You need to call glFlush/glFinish at the end, glut provides glutSwapBuffers, so in the end of your displayEvent function you need to call glutSwapBuffers to see the effect of your displayEvent function.

Comment: There's no need for `glFlush`, and you definitely don't want to use `glFinish`. `glutSwapBuffers` called at the right place is enough.

Comment: @Reto, i meant to say on gl perspective about glFlush and glFinish not with the current context, yes only glutSwapBuffers is enough, as glutSwapBuffers internally does a glFlush